# Is storing a string within the id of a div advisable?

Tags: html, store

Alright, so I'm quite new to css/html/javascript, and I was thinking of storing a value temporarily within the ID of a div. I won't use the ID to select or css, just to store the value. Is this recommended?

Comment: You're probably better of using [`data-something` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you consider looking at `data-xx` attributes instead, e.g.:

```
<div id="1" data-info="Your string goes here"></div>
```

As that is what these are designed for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes